# Displaying popup messgae in Jung

Tags: java, jung, jung2

I have created a network which consists of number of vertexes and edges. How do I show a popup message over a vertex when I move the mouse to that vertex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractPopupGraphMousePlugin and its subclasses are what you want:
http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/control/AbstractPopupGraphMousePlugin.html

Look for its use in PluggableRendererDemo and in GraphEditorDemo.  (Other samples also use it; those samples show how to create subclasses.)

Comment: Thank you sir. Ill check in that website