# setToolTip in JUNG for several vertices

Tags: java, jung, jung2

I have nearly 36 vertiecs in one graph.I would like to insert tooltip box for each and every vertices. I have to show further information about the vertices with the help of tooltip box.

```
 vv.setToolTipText("<html><center>Breast Neoplasms<p>"+ "Gene interactions</p> </center></html>");
```

The above code is for displaying general information. But i need tooltip for every vertices in my graph. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911867/displaying-popup-messgae-in-jung/.

Comment: But i Couldnt insert tooltip message for each and every vertices sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the required output uisng the following code.

```
  vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer(new Transformer<String, String>() {
        public String transform(String v) {

        //  i=0;
            try {

                 String bb = "SELECT * FROM interr";
                Statement pest = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet v1 = pest.executeQuery(bb);   
                while(v1.next())
                    if(v.toString().equals(v1.getString("Mole1")))
                 na[i] = v1.getString("Pubchem_ID");
                System.out.println(na[i]);
                v=na[i].toString();
                return "PUBMED:"+v.toString();
            }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);

        }
            return null;

        }
    });
```